# How does Wordpress detect text-only content?

Tags: php, wordpress, browser, wordpress-theming

The code I've pasted below is from the *header.php* of the twentyeleven theme.  I would just like to know which function to look for that detects text-only content?

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
<h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
<?php /* Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu 
         and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
<div class="skip-link">
  <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" 
     title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="skip-link">
  <a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" 
     title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>">
      <?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>
    </a>
</div>
<?php /* Our navigation menu. If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back 
      to wp_page_menu. The menu assigned to the primary location is the one used. 
      If one isn't assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</nav><!-- #access -->
```

The reason I ask is that I am testing this code with a theme I'm working on, and it's behaving as if my theme is text-only, even though the page has images etc.  Also, it's Firefox on Windows, so obviously the browser is ok(checked it in Chrome also). So basically I'm trying to figure out the criteria that makes it seem as if it's 'text-only' or how this code is executed.
I looked in various .js files also, but I don't see anything there.  Seems this is being done with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to have to agree with Andreas.  The first place I start when stuff looks likes it's still 1991, is the css.  Are all of your stylesheets linked properly?  Wordpress can get tricky with stylesheets and script linking since there are so many php calls going on.

You may try editing the header file to include this bit of PHP.  Followed by whatever your file address in within the root of your blogs template directory.

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
```

The only other thing that I can think of is that for some reason your site is misfiring when it looks to see if the site being viewed via screen-reader, which would force it to display nothing but text.  You could try removing that bit of code, and seeing if that works.  But this would still indicate that there is something wrong with that part of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like you got some URLs for the images wrong?

You might get more answers at [Wordpress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The images are in the same directory. But thanks for the answer - I didn't know there was a separate site.